# Postfix individual transport exception

Tags: postfix

(Can I not start out with a greeting?)

I am running a Postfix server, which has the following `transport_map`:

```
charlie.localdomain smtp:[sierra.localdomain]:10025
```

Now I want mail for *one* specific recipient routed through another listener, which has a special milter, so I add the recipient to the transport map:

```
specialguy@charlie.localdomain    smtp:[127.0.0.1]:1025
```

... and add the `:1025` listener to `charlie`'s `master.cf`, like so (milter omitted for now for simplicity):

```
1025      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/spamsocket
    -o alias_maps=
    -o virtual_alias_maps=
    -o canonical_maps=
    -o sender_canonical_maps=
    -o transport_maps=
    -o default_transport=smtp:[sierra.localdomain]:10025
```

Now I send a mail for `specialguy`. It is received well enough:

```
Apr 13 16:49:17 charlie postfix/smtpd[25477]: Anonymous TLS connection established from tango.localdomain...
Apr 13 16:49:18 charlie postfix/smtpd[25477]: 09B26200F887: client=tango.localdomain
Apr 13 16:49:18 charlie postfix/cleanup[25481]: 09B26200F887: message-id=...
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/qmgr[21852]: 09B26200F887: from=<sender>, size=2056, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/smtpd[25477]: disconnect from tango.localdomain
```

... and correctly forwarded to the `1025` listener, but starts looping immediately:

```
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/spamsocket/smtpd[25484]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/spamsocket/smtpd[25484]: B051120AD3E2: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/cleanup[25481]: B051120AD3E2: message-id=...
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/qmgr[21852]: B051120AD3E2: from=<sender>, size=3798, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/spamsocket/smtpd[25484]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/smtp[25483]: 09B26200F887: to=<specialguy@charlie.localdomain>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:1025, delay=1.7, delays=1.7/0.01/0.02/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B051120AD3E2)
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/qmgr[21852]: 09B26200F887: removed
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/spamsocket/smtpd[25484]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/spamsocket/smtpd[25484]: B9A4B20AD3E9: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/cleanup[25481]: B9A4B20AD3E9: message-id=...
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/qmgr[21852]: B9A4B20AD3E9: from=<sender>, size=3982, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 16:49:19 charlie postfix/smtp[25483]: B051120AD3E2: to=<specialguy@charlie.localdomain>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:1025, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0/0.02/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B9A4B20AD3E9)
[ ... 40 repeats ... ]
```

It seems to me that the `1025:` listener decides to take a look at the `transport_map` (even though it has been explicitly told not to) and loops the mail back around to itself. Any ideas as to how I can make it not do that?

PS: The rationale for the whole thing is, that the "main" `:25` listener has a spamassassin milter configured, but if a multiple-recipient mail is received, the individual bayes databases are not consulted, presumably due to limitations of the milter protocol. What I want, is for the `:25` receiver to resend all mails to itself at `:1025` *one-by-one* (using some sort of `\*_destination_recipient_limit` parameter I guess), and setup the spamass-milter on the new listener. I am trying to do this experiment as transparently as possible, only affecting `specialguy@` so as to now disrupt normal operation of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The looping happens because the two `smtpd` instances share the same queue.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Postfix_architecture.svg

That is, the mail enters by `:25`, and is put in the `active` queue. `qmgr` then decides to forward to `localhost:1025` as per the `transport_maps` parameter.

The mail now enters the same mailserver on `:1025`, **is put into the same queue**, `20 goto 10`.

One solution is to give the second `smtpd` listener a separate `queue_service_name` and/or `cleanup_service_name`, but that would require a lot of manual modifications to CentOS's SELinux settings.

Solution: Running multiple instances via `postmulti` (http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html)